Is it permissible to take an oath by touching Quran on the name Allah?
Assalamoalaikum!
Can muslims take an oath by touching Quran on the name of Allah.
My question is if permissible to do in Islam on serious matters? Such as saving home, keeping the husband and wife relationship to get their trust back on the their spouse?
For Example, A husband denies to take oath as he says it is not permissible in Islam for touching Quran on the name of Allah. So can he take an oath by touching Quran and on the name of Allah.

This question is similar to: Does Islam permit swearing by anything else other than Allah?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AbduRahman Yes my question is different from the one you referred. Here my question is particularly taking an oath on the name of Allah by “touching Quran”. Like previously people used to go sacred places before Quran for taking an oath on the name of Allah.

Yes! You can swear by the Quran, however there is a difference of opinion on placing hand on Quran for taking an oath.
1. Swearing by Allah’s Names or Attributes:

An oath can only be taken using one of Allah’s names or attributes, such as saying “By Allah” or “By the speech of Allah.”


Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) met `Umar bin Al-Khattab while the latter was going with a group of camel-riders, and he was swearing by his father. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Lo! Allah forbids you to swear by your fathers, so whoever has to take an oath, he should swear by Allah or keep quiet."
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6646


Since the Quran is Allah’s speech, swearing by the Quran is permissible, as it is same as swearing by one of His attributes.


“It is permissible to swear by Allah and His Attributes. The Quran is the Word of Allah, which is one of His attributes, so it is permissible to swear by it .”
(Fatawa al-Lajnah ad-Daimah, 1/354)

2. Placing a Hand on the Quran:
Scholars differ on whether placing a hand on the Quran while swearing is permissible.

Permissible View: Some scholars say it is allowed if a judge, ruler, or authority asks someone to do so in court to emphasize the seriousness of the situation. Historical examples include Uthman bin Affan instructing individuals to swear at significant places, such as the Prophet’s pulpit or near sacred sites like the Kaaba, to underline the gravity of their oath. Another example would be


It says in Qaraar Majma‘ al-Fiqh al-Islami:
Placing the hand on the Mushaf when swearing an oath is not required in order for the oath to be valid, but it is permissible, if the judge sees fit, to confirm the solemnity of the oath and so as to deter the oath-taker from lying. End quote.
Taken from : https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/203252


Opposing View: Other scholars argue that it is not permissible. They state that during the time of the Prophet and his companions, no one was ever asked to place their hand on the Quran. They believe such practices may diminish the Quran’s sanctity, as it was meant to be recited, read, and acted upon—not used as a tool for swearing.


Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
Swearing an oath is not permissible except by Allah, may He be exalted, or by one of His attributes. … If a person swears by Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, then there is no need to bring the Mushaf so that he may swear on it, for swearing on the Mushaf is something that was not done by the righteous earlier generations; it was not done at the time of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) or at the time of the Sahaabah. Even after the Mushaf was compiled, they did not swear on the Mushaf. Rather a person would swear by Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, without swearing on the Mushaf.
End quote from Fataawa Noor ‘ala ad-Darb by Ibn ‘Uthaymeen
Taken from : https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/203252

3.   Imitation of Non-Muslim Practices:

Placing a hand on the Quran to swear is seen as an imitation of Christian practices, such as placing a hand on the Bible. This is considered an innovation and not part of Islamic teachings.

Conclusion :

Swearing by Allah, His names, or His attributes, including the Quran as His speech, is permissible and widely accepted in Islamic teachings. However, the practice of placing a hand on the Quran while swearing remains a topic of scholarly debate.

Some scholars permit it as a solemn act in specific judicial or serious contexts, while others discourage it, citing the absence of such practices during the Prophet’s time and concerns over imitating non-Muslim traditions. Therefore, while swearing by the Quran is permissible, caution should be exercised regarding additional practices to ensure adherence to authentic Islamic principles.


References:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Hp_EvJg3CRU#bottom-sheet


https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/158723

